# Translation of an article

Tags: reference-request, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

I need to read this article

"On the spectrum of an energy operator for atoms with fixed nuclei in subspaces corresponding to irriducible representations of permutation groups"

authors:G.Zhislin, A. Sigalov (Izv. Akad. Nauk. SSSR Ser. Mat. 1965 29 pagg 853-860)

but I've found it in Russian only. Is there anyone who knows the existence of a translation of this article?

Comment: Original authors?

Comment: Yes they are original authors; I talk to the librarian of my university but he found me the article in Russian; he said that he didn't succed in finding translations of them.

Comment: @WillJagy they are not the article I'm searching

Comment: In mathematics/physics, it is always a good idea to have some basic notions of french/english/german/russian. You don't need excellent grammar, just the basic sentences and vocabulary.

Answer (score 4):

There *is* a translation. If you look at reference #172 in [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.3309) then that's given as

```
G. M. Zhislin, A.G. Sigalov. The spectrum of the energy operator
for atoms with ﬁxed nuclei on subspaces corresponding to irreducible
representations of the group of permutations. (Russian) Izv. Akad. Nauk
SSSR Ser. Mat. 29 (1965), p. 835–860. Transl. A.M.S. Ser. 2 91,
p. 263–296 (English translation).
```

So as you can see, an English translation has been published by the AMS. This is the book you're looking for:

```
Eighteen Papers on Analysis and Quantum Mechanics
L. I. Barklon, B. G. Gabdulhaev, V. P. Gačok, K. K. Kolovkin,
A. A. Gončar, R. G. Mamedov, V. A. Matveev, H. S. Muhtarov,
A. A. Privalov, A. G. Sigalov, Ju. L. Šmul'jan, M. S. Stavskiĭ,
B. M. Stepanov, S. A. Teljakovskiĭ, V. R. Vinokurov, and G. M. Žislin
```

[More info](http://www.ams.org/bookstore?fn=20&arg1=trans2series&ikey=TRANS2-91)

The Russian article is available free of charge [in PDF form](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3076&option_lang=eng) btw. This PDF contains copy-and-paste'able text; in particular, you can feed it to google translate if you're very much in a hurry.